# element.parentNode.removeChild no funciona con textarea?

Tags: javascript

Después de mucho testeo creo que he dado con este posible error y no se como solucionarlo.

Tengo muchos inputs y un solo textarea, cuando llamo a la función que elimina los inputs lo hace bien, pero cuando se encuentra con este textarea me da el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
```

Este es parte del código html:

```js
function borrar_linea(contador){
        removeElement('nombre2_'+contador);
        console.log("1"); //SI MUESTRA
        removeElement('nombre_'+contador);
        console.log("2"); //NO MUESTRA
}

function removeElement(elementId) {
var element = document.getElementById(elementId); 
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}

borrar_linea("1");
```

```html
<input type="text" value="test" id="nombre2_1" name="nombre2_1" class="form-control text-left">
   <textarea id="nombre_1" name="nombre_1" rows="1">Item 1</textarea>
   <input type="text" value="117.463" id="pre_1" name="pre_1" class="form-control text-left">
```

Comment: Tu ejemplo tal y como lo has puesto funciona sin problemas...

Comment: El problema es que en algún momento coges un elemento que no existe y este es nulo. Por eso en ese momento no puede hacer el element.parentNode. Añade console.log(element); debajo de console.log(elementId); y a ver cuando se da ese caso.

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia pues después de todos los inputs, se da cuando llega al textarea, alli es cuando me da el error.

Comment: Podrías poner el html y la función completa para ver que pasos sigues y ver mejor donde falla?

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia ya he actualizado el post principal

Comment: @Kiko_L creo que te has liado en tu respuesta...

Comment: Despues de obtener el elemento en la funcion removeElement mete esto: `console.log(element); console.log(elementId)`. A ver que podemos sacar de ello

Comment: Sí que había leído mal el id pero acabo de editar tu ejemplo para crear el snippet y no veo que esté fallando.

Comment: @Kiko_L ¿por qué editaste la pregunta para hacerlo funcionar? Debiste haber escrito una respuesta, dejando la pregunta tal y como estaba planteada. Primero porque es así como funciona el sitio, segundo, porque el OP puede recibir otras propuestas de solución. Tienes suficiente reputación como para saber esto, ¿no?

Comment: Hola, no edité la respuesta para que funcionara, la edité para añadir su código como snippet. Si ves la edición lo único que hago es llamar a la función `borrar_linea` para poder ver el funcionamiento de su código (que no he tocado y que es correcto). Como comentario, creo que tu frase "Tienes suficiente reputación como para saber esto, ¿no?" sobra porque no aporta nada a la pregunta.